# What CSS makes a "follow me" button on the side of my webpage?

Tags: css

I've seen a little "tab" or "bookmark" on the side of many webpages with a "follow me on twitter" button in it. How do accomplish that in CSS? (I suspect I'm using absolute or fixed positioning.)

**EDIT:**

I'm looking at the one [described in this web page](http://www.techzoomin.com/plugin-tofix-scrolling-follow-me-twitter-badge-on-sidebar/). I want to use it to run some jQuery on my page, but I like the overall concept.

Comment: Like the one on this page: http://www.techzoomin.com/plugin-tofix-scrolling-follow-me-twitter-badge-on-sidebar/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<a id="twitterbadge" href="http://twitter.com/youraccount">Twitter!</a>
```

CSS:

```
#twitterbadge {
position: [fixed|absolute]; /* if you don't want it to scroll, use fixed */
right: 0;
top: 50%;
width: [width of badge];
height: [height of badge];
display: block;
background: transparent url([url of img]) no-repeat 0 0;
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Comment: that should be it. give it a shot and let me know if it isn't quite working.

Comment: @Jason - will do, but why so negative? ;-)

Comment: @moshe ha, well i just haven't tested it, that's all. i may have missed one or two things.

Comment: Erm, what's with the `text-indent`?

Comment: the `text-indent` allows you to have text in your link but not have it visible. it's an accessibility thing. for instance, if someone with a screen reader or someone with their css turned off came to your site, they would know what that is because whatever text in your link would show up instead of the image.

Comment: I changed the `right: 100%` to `right:0`. The way you did it would offset the tab by "100%", or move it out of the visible plane.

Answer (score 0):

And you could even use `position: fixed;` if you want the badge/button "follow" you when you scroll, as it's done quite a few places.

Comment: I'm actually using this as a "control panel of sorts", but yes, makes sense.